# Select a tag after an nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select an element after a given `:nth-child()` using CSS?

```
div:nth-child(1) + p { font-size: 40pt; }
```

Not working for me, I'm confused.

https://jsfiddle.net/3mfygmjj/1/

Comment: `+ p` == next, `> p` == immediate descendent

Comment: It really depends on the structure of your HTML. Have you tried `div:nth-child(3)  p`?

Comment: Can you post your markup as well?

Comment: What your code does is selecting a `p` which is a child of the 3rd `div` element. Which `p` is selected depends on your selector.

Comment: You should probably take a moment to read the documentation from the W3 Consortium about the [Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

Answer (score 3):

```
div:nth-child(3) > p { font-size: 40pt; }
```

will select every p tag which is in the div:nth-child(3) as a direct descendent.

```
div:nth-child(3) p { font-size: 40pt; }
```

will select every p tag which is in the div:nth-child(3), even if nested multiple levels deep in the dom. In this case, the space between the div:nth-child(3) and the p is the important character.

```
div:nth-child(3) + p { font-size: 40pt; }
```

will select a single p tag which is the very first element after the div:nth-child(3) at the same dom level (not inside other elements).

```
div:nth-child(3) ~ p { font-size: 40pt; }
```

will select *every* p tag which is after the div:nth-child(3) at the same dom level.

Comment: Ok @Michael_B, I did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the one after `nth-child(3)`, why not select `nth-child(4)`?
try `nth-child(3) + div` for the child directly after.
try `nht-child(3) ~ div` for every child after

More on smashing magazine: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/#2-child-selector

Comment: I Tried this, but and dont know what im doing wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/3mfygmjj/1/

Comment: You were using the adjecent sibling (+) selector, but you want to go inside: https://jsfiddle.net/gp44zspr/

Comment: Yes, thx. But i need only the first direct one, so the + is not working.

I need to go inside and select the first or nth-child, thx 

    div:nth-child(1) > p:first-child { font-size: 40pt; }